# Dns doesn't return cellphones hostname and their connection to a network

Tags: c#, dns

I have an app which finds the IPAddress of the local computer and returns the hostnames of all other devices connected to network.

However if I connect my phone , my app doesn't find it.Do they use a different protocol or something?

I use the Dns class from the System.Net assembly.

Comment: Is you phone in the same subnet?  The device are found only in the same subnet and only if the ARP Protocol is enabled on the phone.  I do not think ARP is implemented on phones.

Comment: if you showed us what the app code actually does, it might be easier to understand

Comment: You would have to run some kind of DNS in you network - often this can be set up on your router.